# Why does Spock recommend this not be spoken of anymore?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

At the end of ST:DIS 2x14, Spock recommends that

> all officers remaining with knowledge of these events must be ordered never to speak of Discovery, its spore drive, or her crew again

in order to prevent the experienced series of events from unfolding again.

This left me deeply confused.

I understand that the data

> gathered from the Sphere

was instrumental in

> Control gaining self-awareness

Thus, the plan was to send

> the ship along with the data, which is magically locked to the ship, off into the far future where it is out of reach.

So, **what in the world is Spock's recommendation supposed to achieve in-universe?**

> Given that various methods of time travel are known in the 23rd century, it is conceivable no-one should know the data is on Discovery. But about the rest - surely, Starfleet cannot just deny the existence of the Discovery's crew. And what does the spore drive have to do with it, anyway? As far as I remember, it played a significant role during several events of the Klingon war, which are definitely noted in Starfleet's historical records, but it was completely irrelevant to Control's rise.

Comment: Bad writing.  It answers many questions about Discovery.

Comment: @starpilotsix - https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12432/can-something-be-done-about-unconstructive-comments-in-star-trek-discovery-quest

Comment: not being snarky - it *is* a good out of universe reason to reconcile how none of these events were ever mentioned

Answer (score 4):

## It prevents people from asking deeper questions

> There's no evidence it exploded (hence the intense questioning). We're not told everything they told Starfleet, but let's assume they omitted the Sphere data debacle. Starfleet knew about Control but would be puzzled why Control was so focused on Discovery. Maybe someone would boot Control back up to ask. If they had notified them of the Sphere data, it would have been presumed lost. By pretending that Discovery was lost, in the absence of other data, Starfleet would stop asking questions (we've seen this elsewhere [when convenient lies are used to cover up things](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Clues_(episode)))

## It stops this Section 31 program

> Only Ashe Tyler in Section 31 knows about the time travel program now (presumably, since Control purges the leadership of Section 31, the only other people to know outside of Pike's Enterprise) and he knows what's at stake if he chooses to pursue it as its leader. It's also safe to assume that this stops the Klingons from pursuing it as well, knowing that it could reawaken a monster. If they said "Oh, Burnham flew her Time Suit and Discovery to the 32nd Century", someone would say "Really? We need one of those" and then you're back in the same mess, with people trying to steal time crystals and a temporal cold war looming.

Comment: "Starfleet knew about Control but would be puzzled why Control was so focused on Discovery." - if that's the case, wouldn't Starfleet be extraordinarily interested in probing deeper and thus see any ban on mentioning the events again as highly counterproductive? I see why some parts of this ban (not mentioning the spore drive still seems completely arbitrary to me) could help Spock and the others maintain their cover story, but Spock cannot base his recommendation to Starfleet on this reasoning.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper But if Discovery were destroyed, how would you do that? You can't find the ship and booting Control back up could be dangerous. Moreover, how do you know Control didn't destroy Discovery because it was in the way? It did that to all the Section 31 crews. I agree it was awkward, but the idea was that, if they presented a united front, in the absence of other evidence, they wouldn't go looking for Discovery

Comment: It also stops Control from simply playing the long game and going into hiding until Discovery shows up again in the future.

Comment: @Machavity: From Starfleet's point of view, the Discovery is assumed to have been destroyed, but a few question marks remain (no debris etc.). In the best case, it has indeed been destroyed, in the worst case, it has been taken over by Control and gone into hiding. It seems vital for Starfleet to make sure said worst case has not happened, and the best way to ensure any trace of a surviving Discovery is immediately correctly identified and reported to Starfleet appears to be to widely circulate the knowledge about the ship and its special capabilities. I agree "if they presented a united ...

Comment: ... front, in the absence of other evidence, they wouldn't go looking for Discovery" is the idea behind Pike's, Number One's, and Spock's misreporting of what happened. But Starfleet doesn't seem to have any incentive to prevent any further investigation of Discovery's loss - and actively suggesting to prevent such an investigation looks like a huge red flag to me, saying "I'm hiding something and I want to avoid that I, or any of the other few hundred witnesses who were there, will be questioned any further."

Comment: @BrianOrtiz: Please explain. How does a ban on disseminating any information on the (presumed destroyed) Discovery, its crew, or its spore drive stop Control from going into hiding until it finds another opportunity to evolve (with or without the Sphere data)? If anything, making sure no-one knows about what happened seems to *facilitate* Control going into hiding because it wouldn't be recognized for what it is.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Control had centralized itself into Leland. Once *he* died, control was reduced to the original program which could be purged by Ash Tyler. That is why the control fleet went static when Leland died and Discovery went through the rift. Since the entire control fleet was destroyed, any backups were also destroyed.

Comment: @sabbahillel: That's a rather unlikely twist (could Control really be so stupid to make a (slightly upgraded, yet still comparably fragile) human body a single point of failure?), but even though it's probably true as per the writers' intention, there is no way for Starfleet to know that.

Comment: The fact that Control is so paranoid as to regard any other sentient being as a threat would mean that it would regard any other sentient being as a threat to be eliminated. This would include any active backups. Also it would not regard the Leland body as a point of failure as it would consider itself capable of taking over a new body as it did Leland.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The real subterfuge is that Discovery was supposedly destroyed. The "gag order" supports this and prevents anyone from discovering the truth.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz: "that Discovery was supposedly destroyed" - that's what Pike, Spock & Co. want Starfleet to believe. But Starfleet has only their word for it. From Starfleet's point of view, the destruction of Discovery is at best an unverified report, if not downright dubious. That's what doesn't make sense to me. I agree the "gag order" would come in convenient for Pike's cover story, but what incentive could *Starfleet* possibly have to go along with that suggestion, rather than to dig as deeply and thoroughly as they can to verify - or disprove - the story? It seems to me that Spock ...

Comment: ... suggesting the "gag order" himself should immediately cast additional doubt on the report about the destruction of Discovery. It's comparable to a situation where the only witness at a crime scene insists: "Yes, that guy stumbled and fell into his own knife, backward, before rolling over. Oh, by the way, I think the best course of action is to avoid any further investigation on the case!" It's like waving a huge sign saying: "I'm hiding something and I'm trying to prevent you from finding out!"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper So you have multiple senior officers, including a highly decorated captain, claiming that Discovery was destroyed **during a huge battle**. Which part of that would sound suspicious to Starfleet?

Comment: @BrianOrtiz: For instance, the part where the question about inexplicable sensor readings is just countered with a snappish remark. After watching the questioning scene again, it sure seems like the person questioning Pike, Spock, Number One, and Tyler doesn't believe a single word of what they're saying (hence, for instance, the repeated inquiry whether that's their official response). And that's no surprise, given the way they cut off his questions ("Do you think she what?"), answer with the same short-spoken, apparently agreed upon responses ("I saw Discovery explode."), and try to be ...

Comment: ... as uncooprative as possible ("How long is this gonna take?"; "I believe the exact date is in the logs."; ...). IMHO, the entire dialogue is written in a typical "You know full well we're lying, but you can't prove it." tone. (One has to wonder anyway to what lengths they went to convince hundreds of crewmen to play along with the lie, and to forge sensor records on the Enterprise and the shuttles.) But even if Starfleet doesn't doubt the integrity of their officers, at least considering the possibility that the Enterprise crew were mistaken about Discovery's destruction seems cautious ...

Comment: ... until positive evidence of said destruction is found. I still see no reason what benefit Starfleet could expect from limiting the possibility of a future investigation.